# django admin registering dynamic model from action

Tags: python, django, dynamic, django-models, django-admin

I have strange problem. In admin.py I can say:

```
admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

and this is obviously fine. Now I want this model to be loaded automatically as an result of user action:

```
def user_action_from_admin_panel(......):
    .....
    admin.site.register(MyModel)
```

MyModel class gets shows up in the admin as plain text without links.
Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: Try to restart the server after the action is completed and see if it works. Let know if the issue persists.

Comment: It may be easier to suggest a different way to accomplish what you're trying to do than to solve the actual problem you're having. Can you explain why you want to do this?

Comment: hmmm I have dynamic models created on fly so I want them to be registered on request in admin panel. HoWEVER above example uses normal static model defined in models.py, nothing fancy here

Comment: I don't think I'll have a helpful answer, but I'm fascinated by the question. How do you create database tables to match your dynamic models? How do you persist the dynamic models across server restart, and share them between server processes in a multi-process deployment? I suspect you'll find nobody has done this before and there are many hurdles to getting it to work.

Comment: well in fact it's not that difficult and I was suprised that django and python are so powerfull - read this first if you interested: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

Answer (score 2):

May be you need this

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import clear_url_caches
from django.utils.importlib import import_module


def user_action_from_admin_panel(......):
    .....
    admin.site.register(MyModel)
    reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
    clear_url_caches()
```

Answer (score 2):

> models created dynamically will not show up in the admin unless their `app_labels` match up with packages listed in INSTALLED_APPS
>
> This is again by design, and should not be considered a bug.

Make sure you are adding `app_label` while creating a model

```
model = create_model('DynamicModel', app_label='existing_app')
```

Also reload your url conf so that new model gets links

```
# after creating model
from django.utils.importlib import import_module
reload(import_module(settings.ROOT_URLCONF))
```

Source: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels#Admininterface

Answer (score 0):

I have black links if I don't permissions to add/change.

Try re-define your admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

    def has_change_permission(self, request):
        return True
...

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason possibly is because Django couldn't find any URL match with that model for admin section. Hence, that model line in admin area will be set at disabled and no additional add or edit links.

For some cases, your code for registering models are triggered after the building of admin URLs ([django.contrib.admin.site.AdminSite.get_urls()](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L242)).A workaround solution is to update the whole admin urlpatterns of the global URLs, or using a Django apps named [django-quickadmin](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-quickadmin), it will automatically load all custom models into admin without making any additional code.