# Why do my models show up disabled in django admin?

Tags: python, django, admin

I'm generating django models dynamically during my app start up from a yaml description file. I register them in django admin, but they show up disabled in admin interface. Looks like [this](http://oi45.tinypic.com/sne70w.jpg).

I've created manage.py command to dynamically create models from description file in yaml format.

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.management import call_command

import yaml

from generation.generate import generate_fields, generate_model


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Generates or updates django models from specified file'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        try:
            f = open(args[0], 'r')
            models = yaml.safe_load(f)
            f.close()
            for name, definition in models.items():
                fields = generate_fields(definition['fields'])
                generate_model(name, definition['title'], fields, "generation", "generation.models")
            call_command('syncdb', interactive=True)
        except IOError:
            self.stderr.write('Cannot open file: {0}'.format(args[0]))
        except yaml.YAMLError as e:
            self.stderr.write('Cannot parse file {0}: {1}'.format(args[0], e))
```

I startup this command from root urls.py like this:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from generation import views
from generation.management.commands.updatemodels import Command

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.main, name='main'),
    # url(r'^modgen/', include('modgen.foo.urls')),

    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

Command().handle('models.yaml')
```

I generate models and register in admin in this way:

```
from sys import stderr
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models


class Types():
    INT = 'int'
    CHAR = 'char'
    DATE = 'date'


def generate_model(model_name, model_title, fields, app_label, module):
    class Meta:
        pass
    if app_label:
        setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)
    if model_title:
        setattr(Meta, 'verbose_name_plural', model_title)
    attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}
    if fields is not None:
        attrs = dict(attrs.items() + fields.items())
    model = type(model_name, (models.Model,), attrs)
    admin.site.register(model)


def generate_fields(definition):
    fields = {}
    for field in definition:
        fields[field['id']] = generate_field(field['title'], field['type'])
    return fields


def generate_field(title, field_type):
    if field_type == Types.CHAR:
        return models.CharField(title, max_length=255)
    elif field_type == Types.INT:
        return models.IntegerField(title)
    elif field_type == Types.DATE:
        return models.DateField(title)
    else:
        stderr.write('Unknown field type specified: {0}'.format(field_type))
```

Why do models show up disabled in admin interface? Django registers them succesfully.

Comment: There is also a similar question here: [django admin registering dynamic model from action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13184154/django-admin-registering-dynamic-model-from-action). But it's also unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, first you need to edit (or create) file `generation/admin.py`, then add this code for registering application models in django-admin part.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from myproject.generation.models import Rooms, Users

class RoomsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


class UsersAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass


admin.site.register(Rooms, RoomsAdmin)
admin.site.register(Users, UsersAdmin)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that wouldn't help me, because I create models dynamically. I don't know what models I will create until the start up of my Django app.